# Can I run specific tests on Chrome and Firefox in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, jasmine, protractor

In my conf file I have multiCapabilities on, and have around 20 suites.
When I run my test suites, tests run both on Chrome and Firefox, and somehow Firefox takes almost double the time to execute same number of test cases than what Chrome does.
So I want to divide my test cases so that half of them run on Chrome and rest on Firefox.
I know there is shardTestFiles option, but it wouldn't work as am using same workspace for my apps and don't really want to run tests in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of spec files to run to each `capability` in your `multicapabilities` array. From the protractor source:

```
/**
 * Additional spec files to be run on this capability only.
 */
specs?: string[];
```

It would look something like this:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: "chrome",
    specs: ['spec1.js','spec2.js']
}, {
    browserName: "firefox",
    specs: ['spec3.js','spec4.js']
}],
```

In this case spec 1 and 2 would run on Chrome and specs 3 and 4 would run on Firefox.

Comment: But can I categorize the specs later in suites too? Like for an example if I have spec 1, 2 & 3 in chrome and then specs 4, 5 & 6 in firefox, can I have suites like suite1 having tests 1, 2 & 4 and suite 2 having the remaining ones? Am asking this because I have around 30 suites in which I have categorized my test cases and I dont want a single run of conf file but want to execute according to suites.

Comment: I wasn't sure so I tried it out real quick. I setup 4 spec files and set 1 and 3 to run in chrome and then 2 and 4 to run in firefox. Then I setup two suites, suite1 is set to run specs 1 and 2 and suite 2 is set to run specs 3 and 4. The tests ran in the browsers they were set to run in so it looks like this is possible

Comment: Thank you for checking this out but I changed mine and the tests still run on both browsers. When the Chrome run completes, same tests start running on firefox.